# Using Custom Value Options in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently using a custom field called "Developing" to show whether or not a news story is a developing story. The custom field has a couple of values: a blank option (meaning it is not developing), "Yes," and "Was Developing." This is the code I use to display the word "Developing" in front of a news story title:

```
<?php if (get_meta('developing') != "") { ?>Developing: <?php } ?>
```

While it shows "Developing" when I've hit Yes, it also shows "Developing" when I change the option to "Was Developing." I'm assuming this is because I'm calling up the entire thing and not distinguishing between its options in the coding. Does anyone know if I can even do this? For example, can you have different messages show for each option? Something like using "developing's yes option means show this" instead of just "developing means this" like above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your key', true);` instead of `get_meta();`
compare values like

```
$developing = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'developing', true);

if ($developing == 'value') {
  // value is matched
} elseif ($developing == 'value2') {
  // value 2 is matched
} else {
  // not matched
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should **Yoda-case** the conditionals - i.e. `'value' == $developing`, instead of `$developing == 'value'`.

Comment: @ChipBennett thanks but it's my style and i think there is nothing anything wrong to compare values, may be you know better.

Comment: There's actually a very good reason. If you make a syntax error, and write `$developing = 'value'` instead of `$developing == 'value'`, then the value of the variable is set instead of compares, and the conditional always returns true. If Yoda-cased, then `'value' = $developing` will return a syntax error, instead of setting the variable and returning always true.

Comment: @ChipBennett well i am totally agree and i think i need to change my style, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. WordPress has no `get_meta()` function; if you're using `get_post_meta()`, then see @Anjum's answer.
2. Your conditional is logically incorrect: `get_meta('developing') != ""`. You're saying *if the value is **anything other than** an empty string*, then do something. Both `developing` and `was developing` are non-empty strings, and will cause that conditional to return true. Instead, use `if ( 'Developing' == get_post_meta( ... ) ) {`